# System.out resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: https://... when I try to insert picture from web to listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

Following this tutorial http://www.michenux.net/android-around-me-tutorial-974.html and using  Android-Universal-Image-Loader I've create a custom listview where I want to show one imageview and three textview.

This is the listview row:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="5dp">

<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:id="@+id/llLogo"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true">

      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true">
      </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llTextos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/llLogo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvNom"
        android:textColor="#000099">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvDescripcio">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:id="@+id/tvDistancia"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ff0000">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the part of the adapter where I fill the row with the data.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    PlaceHolder placeHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.listview_row_empreses, null);
        placeHolder = PlaceHolder.generate(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(placeHolder);
    } else {
        placeHolder = (PlaceHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    placeHolder.nom.setText(empreses.get(position).getNom());
    placeHolder.descripcio.setText(empreses.get(position).getDescr_curta());
    placeHolder.distancia.setText(empreses.get(position).getLatitud());

    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
        .build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(empreses.get(position).getLogo(), placeHolder.logotip);
    Log.d("TAG", "URL imatge obtesa: " + empreses.get(position).getLogo());

    return (convertView);
}
```

I'm getting the data from a sqlite database.

When I execute the app, the textview are filled with the right information, but the imageview remains blank. The ic_launcher disappears and none picture is shown.

In the logcat appears this shown in green:

> > 05-27 19:15:54.607: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: (I don't have enough reputation to show more than 2 links. Here in the logcat shows the url of the picture)
> >     05-27 19:15:54.737: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: (I don't have enough reputation to show more than 2 links. Here in the logcat shows the url of the picture)
> >     05-27 19:15:54.747: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: (I don't have enough reputation to show more than 2 links. Here in the logcat shows the url of the picture)
> >     05-27 19:15:54.757: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: (I don't have enough reputation to show more than 2 links. Here in the logcat shows the url of the picture)
> >     05-27 19:15:54.777: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: 
> >     05-27 19:15:54.897: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: (I don't have enough reputation to show more than 2 links. Here in the logcat shows the url of the picture)
> >     05-27 19:15:54.977: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: (I don't have enough reputation to show more than 2 links. Here in the logcat shows the url of the picture)
> >     05-27 19:15:55.007: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: (I don't have enough reputation to show more than 2 links. Here in the logcat shows the url of the picture)
> >     05-27 19:15:55.057: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: (I don't have enough reputation to show more than 2 links. Here in the logcat shows the url of the picture)
> >     05-27 19:15:55.117: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: 
> >     05-27 19:15:55.267: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: (I don't have enough reputation to show more than 2 links. Here in the logcat shows the url of the picture)
> >     05-27 19:15:55.287: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: (I don't have enough reputation to show more than 2 links. Here in the logcat shows the url of the picture)
> >     05-27 19:15:55.317: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: (I don't have enough reputation to show more than 2 links. Here in the logcat shows the url of the picture)
> >     05-27 19:15:55.327: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: (I don't have enough reputation to show more than 2 links. Here in the logcat shows the url of the picture)
> >     05-27 19:15:55.347: I/System.out(10203): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:

Which can be the problem?

Comment: I've tried to follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/ and this one http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/imageview/android-how-to-load-image-from-url-in-imageview/ but the logcat always show the same missages in green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find where was exactly the problem, buy I solved it using the picasso library.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are referring to the image via an HTTP URI. The expected URI is a BitMap URI instead.

Comment: Sorry! I could not understand your point. Could you please explain.

Comment: @RahulRastogi, a URI can be an HTTP URI (i.e. a URL) or a URI representing a different kind of resource, in this case a BitMap. See here: http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/URI

Comment: That's right. To be clear, IT IS NOT THE URL of a bitmap. It is a sort of descriptor that describes the bitmap.